# How can I add JWindow to NetBeans project and edit it with GUI editor?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-7

There is only an option to add JFrame and JPanel to project. I tried editing JFrame class to extend JWindow instead, but it leaves NetBeans' autogenerated code with errors, and this code can't be edited.

Comment: Create you're self a `JFrame` form and change the `extends JFrame` to `extends JWindow`, fix the imports.  Do this BEFORE you make any changes.  Works fine for me.

Comment: This leaves this (now invalid) line, which can't be edited: setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

Comment: What version of netbeans are you using??

Comment: I think the way I've done it in the past is to simply use a `JPanel` as the base template :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own template...

Place these two files in `...\NetBeans\7.2.1\config\Templates\GUIForms` folder.

On Windows 7 that's `C:\Users\{your user name}\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2.1\config\Templates\GUIForms`

**JWindow.java**

```
<#assign licenseFirst = "/*">
<#assign licensePrefix = " * ">
<#assign licenseLast = " */">
<#include "../Licenses/license-${project.license}.txt">

<#if package?? && package != "">
package ${package};

</#if>
/**
 *
 * @author ${user}
 */
public class ${name} extends javax.swing.JWindow {

    /** Creates new form ${name} */
    public ${name}() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Generated Code ">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents() {
        pack();
    }
    // </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(${name}.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(${name}.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(${name}.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(${name}.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ${name}().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables

}
```

**JWindow.form**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<Form version="1.3" type="org.netbeans.modules.form.forminfo.JFrameFormInfo">
  <SyntheticProperties>
    <SyntheticProperty name="formSizePolicy" type="int" value="1"/>
  </SyntheticProperties>

</Form>
```